# Django HTML iterate trough a dynamic dictionary name

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to create a website where part of the website I'm using dynamic tabs in html where each tab will show different data.

Now what I'm trying to do is that in the views.py I'm creating different dictionaries for the different tabs. So far I have created the below in the views.py file.

```
def display_rpt (request):
    alltrasfData={}
    sec = Section.objects.all()
    for key in sec:
        transactions = Transaction.objects.values('feast_year__title','feast_year','feast_group__title','section','section__short').filter(section_id=key.id).order_by('section','-feast_year','-feast_group__title').annotate(Total_income=Sum('income_amt'),Total_Expenditure=Sum('expenditure_amt'))
        subtotal = Transaction.objects.values('section','feast_year','feast_year__title').filter(section_id=key.id).annotate(Total_income=Sum('income_amt'),Total_Expenditure=Sum('expenditure_amt'))
        grandtotal = Transaction.objects.values('section').filter(section_id=key.id).annotate(Total_income=Sum('income_amt'),Total_Expenditure=Sum('expenditure_amt'))
        alltrasfData[f'transactions_{key.id}']=transactions
        alltrasfData[f'subtotal_{key.id}']=subtotal
        alltrasfData[f'grandtotal_{key.id}'] = grandtotal
    alltrasfData['sec']=sec
    return render(request, 'homepage/reports.html',alltrasfData)
```

Just to give you an idea some dictionaries that there are in the alltrasfData are:

'transactions_1','transactions_2','transactions_3'

Is there a way in Django html where I can iterate trough these different dictionaries with dynamic dictionary name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `dict` in templates quite easily using [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) template tag.

```
{% for key, values in alltrasfData.items %}
    {% if 'transaction' in key %}
        {% for transaction in values %}
            <p>feast_year: {{transaction.feast_year}}</p>
            <p>...</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% elif 'subtotal' in key %}
        # logic for subtotal goes here
        # ...
    {% else %}
         # logic for grandtotal goes here
        # ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ... Worked :)

Comment: If this answer solves your question, can you please [mark it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1):

I think store `alltrasfData` in a dictionary `context`, pass it to  `render()` and use the following in HTML:

```
{% for key,value in alltrasfData %}
    print(key,value)
{% endfor %}
```